# Laravel 7 physical relationship between tables not present

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-7

I followed a tutorial about many-to-many relationships with Laravel (7 in my case).

The result is good, I learned a lot, but what I find strange is that I do not have physical relationships between the different tables.

I created a relationship many to many, which should link 3 tables, products, categories and products_categories

My questions :

1- Is it essential to have a physical relationship in the schema of the database?
2- How can I make these relationships appear in my diagram?

Here is a current photo of the database schema :

[image]

In this database, I have links between tables :

[image]

Comment: The clue is in the name; it's called a *structured query* language, so the query defines the structure.

Comment: Hi Stawberry, thank you for your reply.  I always try to be a perfectionist, so I worry about not seeing the relationships.

As you can see in the second photo added to my message, we can clearly see the relationships.

Thanks again.

Comment: What kind of perfectionist allows tables to overlap one another? ;-)

Comment: You can (and arguably, should) define table constraints, but this is not a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laravel relationships are not the same as your database relationships (MySQL, or others).

You don't need to have a database relationship to have your application working. it is really depending on what you are trying to achieve.

If you want to see the relationships between your tables, make sure to specify the foreign keys in your migration Schema (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) such as:

```
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

For pivot tables you can also use a migration Schema as follow:

```
Schema::table('category_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
});
```

Comment: Hi Christophe, thank you for your reply.  Same reply than Stawberry, I always try to be a perfectionist, so I worry about not seeing the relationships.

As you can see in the second photo added to my message, we can clearly see the relationships.

Thanks again.

Comment: Added some more details on how to get your relationships back

Comment: Thank you Christophe, your code is great.  My question, I need a many to many relationship.  The code you added is for a one to many ?  Thanks again.

Comment: if you want many to many you need to have pivot table, the principle would be the same for the schema

Comment: Yes, I understood that I need a pivot table, I have it, you can see it my original message.  I'm going to search into the documentation and Google to add those relationships.

Comment: Thank you for your great reply, during this time, I found the same solution.  I put your reply as the best reply received.  Thanks again.